# JBoss DataSource parameters enabled and Pool

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am currently learning about DataSource configuration in a JBOSS Application Server. In our JBOSS Application Server, there are some datasources configured in the the standalone.xml file. I have a few doubts regarding it. Kindly help in clarifying it.

1. Is Connection Pooling enabled by default in JBOSS 7 or is there any parameter we have to specify to enable the connection pooling?
2. Consider the below datasource configuration, please let me know what is the use of "enabled" parameter? If enabled="true" means this datasource should be made available or if enable="true" means Connection Pooling should be enabled?

```
<datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
  </datasources>
```

3. In the below datasource configuration, enabled parameter is not specified. But  parameters are configured. So is the connection pool enabled or not in this case? Also what is the default value of enabled parameter?

```
<datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
  </datasources>
```

4. In the below datasource configuration, only enabled parameter is defined as enabled="true" and no pool configuration  is present. So is the connection pool enabled or not in this case? Also what is the default value for the pool parameters?

```
<datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
  </datasources>
```

5. In the below datasource configuration, neither enabled parameter or  parameter is defined . So is the connection pool enabled or not in this case?

```
<datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
  </datasources>
```

Kindly help in clarifying the above queries as I am not find able to find a proper documentation t o understand about this parameters.

Thanks in advance.